# In Rails is there a way to group a series of active jobs executing in parallel and be notified when they all complete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job, rails-activejob

In Rails is there a way to group a series of ActiveJobs executing in parallel on different instances of the same queue, and be notified when they all complete?

I'm trying to break up a large process into smaller processes, running on different machines at the same time.

Something like GCD Dispatch Groups: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25

I'm currently running Rails 5.0.0 and Ruby 2.3.1.

I'm currently using DelayedJob, but can switch to a different backing queue if one supported this feature.

When I say different instances of the same queue, I'm specifically referring to multiple worker instances on Heroku.

This seems like a common piece of functionality that someone else would have needed. I've tried searching the web for answers, but I think the combination of words makes irrelevant results come up.

Please let me know if there is more information that I can provide, and thanks in advance for your expertise.

Comment: Sidekiq has batch jobs so you can wrap multiple jobs in a batch and then when that batch completes, do something.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, to comment on my own question...I've also found this that kind of sort of does what I am looking for also: https://github.com/cdale77/active_job_status#job-batches Looks like I was just lacking the batch keyword in my search.